# What is best way of implementing multithreading in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have been following several YouTube demos and tutorials on implementing multi-threaded operations in Java. However, all the tutorials show this following procedure:

```
class Task implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doTask();
    }

    public void doTask() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1500; i++) {
            System.out.print('T');
        }
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Task t = new Task();

        Thread thread = new Thread(t);
        thread.start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1500; i++) {
            System.out.print('M');
        }
    }
}
```

Some demos extends Thread class instead of Runnable, however, they follow a similar concept.

However, one problem that I reckon is that what if I want to have multiple logics in a class that I want to run concurrently, then, I have a issue. Well, Java veterans may know some trick to do so. However, I tried to implement such logic in a different way. Here is the code that I wrote:

```
class Task {
    public void doTask() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1500; i++) {
            System.out.print('T');
        }
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Task t = new Task();

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                t.doTask();
            }
        });
        thread.start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1500; i++) {
            System.out.print('M');
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I can launch several threads and call the particular method that I want run concurrently.

Now, I want to know is there any benefit of implementing multi threaded operation using the first approach and is there any shortcomings of the latter one?

Comment: At the risk of being insulting (or seen as shilling), this question is a little bit like asking "If I want to build a rocket to bring me to the moon and safely bring me back home, should I paint it white or grey?"  The problems of writing safe concurrent code are 1,000,000x more complicated than this particular tiny issue.  Read the first few chapters of _Java Concurrency in Practice_ to give you an idea of what you should _really_ be worrying about.

Answer (score 4):

There is no point in defining a `Runnable` class with a `run()` method that only invokes `doTask`. Just put the contents of `doTask` in `run`.

Or, better, use a lambda:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
  // Stuff you want to do.
});
```

But there is absolutely no good reason to extend `Thread`.

In fact, in many cases you don't want to use `Thread` directly: instead, use an `ExecutorService`, to which you submit `Runnable`/`Callable` instances.

Comment: You could also use method references (using the `Task` class of the OP as example): `Thread thread = new Thread(t::doTask);`

Answer (score 4):

The [Answer by Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66611188/642706) is correct. I just want to emphasize that in modern Java there is rarely any reason to directly address the `Thread` class. The tutorials you read are seriously outmoded; ignore them.

## Executor services

The executor service framework was added to Java 5 to abstract away the chores of thread management.

Look to the [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class to instantiate various implementations of [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

```
ExecutorService es = Executors. … ;
```

To automatically close the [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) executor service and any backing pool of threads, use try-with-resources syntax.

```
try (
    ExecutorService es = Executors. … ;
) {
    …
}
```

Define your tasks as [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) Or [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) objects. Submit them to the to the executor service.

```
try (
    ExecutorService es = Executors. … ;
) {
    es.submit( new MyRunnable() ) ;
    …
}
```

If you want to track the completion of your task, capture the [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) object returned by the `submit` method.

[*Project Loom*](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/loom/Main) brought a new executor service Java 21+ that uses lightweight [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444) ([fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(computer_science))) to use less memory, execute faster, and make blocking very cheap, to allow for millions of threads running. Look for talks by Ron Pressler, Alan Bateman, or José Paumard.

```
try (
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() ;
) {
    es.submit( new MyRunnable() ) ;
    …
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is best way of implementing multithreading in java?

There is no single "best" way.  There are many different ways that have advantages and disadvantages.

- The simple way is to use one of the standard `ExecutorService` implementations and submit your tasks as lambdas or instances of `Runnable` or `Callable`.
- ForkJoin pools are similar, but tuned for a different kind of task where one task forks multiple subtasks and then joins them; e.g. divide and conquer algorithms.
- Another approach is to use a 3rd-party thread pool; e.g. as provided by Guava.
- If you really need to manage your own threads you could implement your own thread pool, but there is probably something "out there" that provided the functionality you need.
- If you have a task that needs to be run periodically (in a thread), look at `TimerTask` or a more sophisticated task scheduling library; e.g. Quartz.
- If you have a situation where the threads are static and long running, you can instantiate and start the `Thread` objects directly, passing the body of the thread as a `Runnable` (or lambda).

Just about the only thing to **avoid** is writing a class that `extends` the `Thread` class.  That is a bad idea.  *If you come across example or demos that do this, **ignore them**.  They are 20+ years out of date or have copied material that is 20 years out of date.*

Extending `Thread` typically results in you embed your business logic in the thread sub-classes `run()` method.  This makes it difficult to adapt your code to use a different thread management strategy.  It also makes unit testing harder

Recommended reading:

- [Thread Pools](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) from the Oracle Java Tutorials.
- [Introduction to Thread Pools in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/thread-pool-java-and-guava)
- ["implements Runnable" vs "extends Thread" in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487)

---

Finally, there is an Java incubator project ("Loom") that is developing a light-weight thread model.  These threads are called "fibres".  It is probably not relevant to you now.

Answer (score 1):

In your simple example there is absolutely no downside (or upside) to using a shared object. But you can run into trouble if you have an mutable variable in your object that is changed in multiple tasks.

```
class Task {
    //Getter
    private long taskId;

    public void doTask() {
        taskId++;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1500; i++) {
            System.out.print('T');
        }
    }
}
```

In this case you would have to use the `synchronized` keyword or AtomicLong. Otherwise you may end up in a race condition and  `taskId` gives wrong values.